# How to fix "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'" on a deployed ASP WebForms website

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asp.net-ajax, iis-10

I have been having an issue with one of my websites where it works perfectly fine while developing, but once it gets published and deployed on IIS, the styling for ONLY the account pages doesn't render, but the functional pages do render properly.

When I have a look in the console, it lists the following errors:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at modernizr?v=inCVuEFe6J4Q07A0AcRsbJic_UE5MwpRMNGcOtk94TE1:3:1)

1.
2.
3. <!DOCTYPE html>
   ^
4.
5.<html lang="en">
6.<head><meta charset="utf-8" /><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" /><title>
```

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at MsAjaxJs?v=D6VN0fHlwFSIWjbVzi6mZyE9Ls-4LNrSSYVGRU46XF81:3:1)

1.
2.
3. <!DOCTYPE html>
   ^
4.
5.<html lang="en">
6.<head><meta charset="utf-8" /><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" /><title>
```

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at WebFormsJs?v=N8tymL9KraMLGAMFuPycfH3pXe6uUlRXdhtYv8A_jUU1:3:1)

1.
2.
3. <!DOCTYPE html>
   ^
4.
5.<html lang="en">
6.<head><meta charset="utf-8" /><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" /><title>
```

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Sys is not defined at Login:61:1

Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize('ctl00$ctl09', 'ctl01', [], [], [], 90, 'ctl00');
^^^
```

Of the first three errors, the page that the link takes me to shows the HTML for the login page, irrespective of if I'm looking at the login page, or any other account page, even though these pages should be showing JavaScript.

I've tried looking for a solution to this, but nothing I have found even relates to the problem I am facing.

The last error leads me to believe that AJAX isn't being loaded properly, and I have no idea why.

Comment: Are you using an UpdatePanel somewhere? And if the page returned by the UpdatePanel has a Response.Write then it could give issues.

Comment: @VDWWD No, there is no UpdatePanel anywhere on the site. The only thing AJAX is being used for is a calendar date selector on the main page of the site.

Comment: Did you add the `ScriptManager` correctly to the page? Secondly, please make sure that the script code is placed at the end of the page code. It would be helpful to provide a minimal code example that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does the AJAX call return what you think it does? If the call returns an error page then it can also generate that error.

Comment: How are you publishing this? Is this a web site,  or a web site application? Have you tried publishing as debug vs release?

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal It's a website, and I just tried publishing with debug configuration, and it got the styling to load on the login page, but there are a few elements of my styling that isn't working, such as the elements on the page aren't centred, but rather pushed up against the left of the page.

Comment: @XudongPeng I don't know what's causing the issue to begin with. So, I don't know what code I could provide to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the fix to it was to add `EnableCdn='true'` to the `<asp:ScriptManager>`.

Once I did that, I stopped receiving the errors entirely, and all my styling loaded just fine after that.